Return a Value When All Child Values are != 1
I'm trying to query a table called pollerstatus to return the nodeid's where the rowstatus != 1 for all of the instances of that nodeid. In the table below I want the SQL query to return nodeid 1012 because that's the only one where all of the rowstatus values !=1.



rowid
nodeid
label
rowstatus




1
1011
LC1
1


2
1011
LC1
1


3
1012
LC2
0


4
1012
LC2
3


5
1012
LC2
0


6
1013
LC3
1


7
1013
LC3
1


8
1014
LC4
4


9
1014
LC4
5


10
1014
LC4
1



The best I've managed to come up with is a count for each nodeid where rowstatus != 1
SELECT COUNT (concat(NodeID, rowstatus)) AS row_count, NodeID
FROM pollerstatus
WHERE rowstatus != 1
group by NodeID

This returns



row_count
nodeid




2
1012


2
1014



But this is no good because as well as returning nodeid 1012 which does have all rowstatus != 1 it also returns nodeid 1014 which doesn't have all rowstatus != 1

You can do a conditional count:
SELECT NodeID
FROM pollerstatus
GROUP BY NodeID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN rowstatus = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0;

This returns no rows because you have rowstatus = 1 on every Node :)
